# Error Symfony HttpFoundation streamdownload laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero descargar un archivo en formato tsv mediante streamdownload para impedir descargar en el disco del servidor, pero a la hora de descargarlo no funciona y me da el siguiente error: **Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse::__construct() must be callable or null, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\altur-erp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory.php** on line 137

Código

```
   $hola="contenido archivo tsv";

 return response()->streamDownload($hola, 'nomfitxer.tsv');
```

Answer (score 0):

Solcionado amigos os dejo por aquí el código.

```
 return response()->streamDownload(function () {
  echo 'Contenido';
  }, 'users.txt');
```

Comment: Que corregiste?